# Checking to see if a char pointer is null - Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, copy-constructor

I am working on the following code

```
class base
{
private:
    char* mycharpointer;
    std::string mystring;

public:
    base() : mycharpointer(NULL) {/*default constructor*/}

    //Copy Constructor
    base(const base& rhs){
        if(mycharpointer != NULL)  ---> Why is this condition true ?
        {
            mycharpointer = new char[ strlen(rhs.mycharpointer + 1)];
            strcpy(this->mycharpointer,rhs.mycharpointer);
        }
        mystring = rhs.mystring;
    }


    base operator=(base& b)
    {   
        if(this == &b) 
            return *this;

        base temp(b); 
        temp.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    //Swap operation
    void swap(base& lhs) {
        std::swap(lhs.mycharpointer,this->mycharpointer);
        std::swap(lhs.mystring,this->mystring);
    }

    //Destructor
    virtual ~base(){
        if(mycharpointer) 
            delete[] mycharpointer;
    }
};

class der : public base
{
public:
    char* mycharpointer_der;
    std::string mystring_der;
    foo* f;

public:
    der():mycharpointer_der(NULL)
    {
    }


    der(const der& rhs) : base(rhs) 
    {
        if(mycharpointer_der) 
        {   
            mycharpointer_der = new char[ strlen(rhs.mycharpointer_der + 1)];
            strcpy(this->mycharpointer_der,rhs.mycharpointer_der); 
        }
        mystring_der = rhs.mystring_der;
        f = new foo(*rhs.f);
    }


    der& operator=(der& d)
    {   
        if(this == &d) //Make sure its not the same class
            return *this;

        base::operator= (d);
        der temp(d); 
        temp.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    //Swap operation
    void swap(der& lhs) {
        std::swap(lhs.mycharpointer_der,this->mycharpointer_der);
        std::swap(lhs.mystring_der,this->mystring_der);
    }

    virtual ~der(){
         if(mycharpointer_der) //Necessary check as to make sure you are not deleting a NULL address otherwise exception thrown.
            delete[] mycharpointer_der;
    }

};



int main()
{
    der d;
    d.mycharpointer_der = "Hello World";
    d.mystring_der = "Hello String";
    der b;
    b = d;
}
```

Now in the above code the copy assignment operator of d is called. which in return calls the copy assignment operator of the base class. In the copy assignment operator of the base class the copy constructor of the base class is called. My question is why is the condition

```
if(mycharpointer != NULL)
```

in the base class turning out as true ? Even when I have explicitly assigned it a NULL in the initialization list of the base class.

Comment: A few things: your base copy constructor should first `delete[] mycharpointer;` then have `if (rhs.mycharpointer != nullptr)` (note the `rhs.`), and it should be `strlen(rhs.mycharpointer) + 1` (note the right parenthesis before the `+1).  Your copy-assignment operator should accept a `const base&`.  Your `swap` argument would more reasonably be called "`rhs`", if you think about the invocation ala `lhs.swap(rhs);` - but that's not a functional problem.  Your destructor doesn't need `if (mycharpointer)` - `delete[]` checks that anyway.  Many analogous errors in `der`....

Comment: The copy constructor doesn't set `mycharpointer` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That check is ridiculous. At the point of construction, when we get into the body, `mycharpointer` is default-initialized and will contain some garbage value  which *may* be `0` but likely won't be.

That said, what happens if `rhs.mycharpointer` is NULL? Then the `strlen` call would fail. That's the `charpointer` whose value you need to be checking:

```
base(const base& rhs)
{
    if (rhs.mycharpointer) {
        mycharpointer = new char[ strlen(rhs.mycharpointer) + 1 ]; 
        //                         outside the parens      ^^^^
        strcpy(this->mycharpointer,rhs.mycharpointer);
    }
    else {
        mycharpointer = NULL;
    }
    mystring = rhs.mystring;
}
```

Or since you're already using `string`, we could keep using `string` for `mycharpointer` too. That has the added benefit of us not even having to write the copy constructor which, as you can see, can be error prone:

```
base(const base& ) = default;
```

Comment: Thats how i kept it initially but then every time  it would get on the strlen method of base class copy constructor I get the error "Unhandled exception at 0x53c4d51c (msvcr100d.dll) in Boost_smartPointers.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001." I am using VS2010

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I realize that I should have done  if (rhs.mycharpointer)  instead of if(mycharpointer != NULL) but now I am curious why was mycharpointer pointing to garbage value didnt I assign it to NULL at the time of constrcution ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar The copy constructor does not call the default constructor - those are two unrelated functions. You don't initialize `mycharpointer` in the initialization list of the constructor, so that makes it default-initialized - which for pointers means it's not initialized to anything.

Answer (score 1):

C++ compiler only make sure the global variable and static variables will be initialized, so In this case, the mycharpointer may actually points to some useless garbage(dangling pointer)

```
base(const base& rhs){
        if(mycharpointer != NULL)  ---> Why is this condition true ?
        {
            mycharpointer = new char[ strlen(rhs.mycharpointer + 1)];
            strcpy(this->mycharpointer,rhs.mycharpointer);
        }
        mystring = rhs.mystring;
    }
```

as mycharpointer actually point to the data allocated on the heap, so if you want to rellocate it, you need to release existing data first.
   something like:

```
    if ( mycharpointer)  {
        delete [] mycharpointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're expecting the default constructor to run before the copy constructor does.

But it won't.